# Empty data while reading data from kafka using Trident Topology

Tags: apache-kafka, trident

I am new to Trident. I am writing a trident topology which reads data from kafka. Topic name is 'test'. I have local kafka setup. I started zookeeper, kafka in local. And created a topic 'test' in kafka and opened the producer and typed the message 'Hello Kafka!'.

I want to read the message 'Hello Kafka' from the 'test' topic using trident.

Below is my code. I am getting empty tuple.

```
    TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
    BrokerHosts brokerHosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");

    TridentKafkaConfig kafkaConfig = new TridentKafkaConfig(brokerHosts, "test");
    kafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    kafkaConfig.bufferSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    kafkaConfig.fetchSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    kafkaConfig.forceFromStart = false;
    OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout opaqueTridentKafkaSpout = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);

    topology.newStream("TestSpout", opaqueTridentKafkaSpout).parallelismHint(1)
      .each(new Fields(), new TestFilter()).parallelismHint(1)
      .each(new Fields(), new Utils.PrintFilter());
```

and this is my TestFilter class code

```
public TestFilter()
{
    //
}

@Override
public boolean isKeep(TridentTuple tuple) {
    boolean isKeep=true;
    System.out.println("TestFilter is called...");
    if (tuple != null && tuple.getValues().size()>0) {
        System.out.println("data from kafka ::: "+tuple.getValues());
    } 
    return isKeep;
}
```

Whenever i type message in kafka producer to the 'test' topic, first sysout getting printed but it doesn't pass the if loop. I am simply getting message 'TestFilter is called...' not more than that.

I want to get the actual data i produced to the 'test' topic. How?

Comment: can you see the message using the console-consumer script ?

Comment: Yes i can see the message using the console-consumer script.

Comment: Can you change `config.forceFromStart=true`

Comment: i added fileds new Fields("str"). It started working.Thanks.

Comment: @Kutty You should've written an answer to you own question for posterity. I encountered the same problem and it wasn't immediately obvious what the source of the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

The problems lies in the parameters to Stream.each. The relevant portion of the javadoc for the method is:

```
each(Fields inputFields, Filter filter)
```

The documentation is't too clear about it, but the semantic is that you should specifies all the fields used by your filter using the *inputFields* parameter.

Storm will then apply a projection on the input tuple and forward it to the *filter*.

Given that you didn't specified any input fields, the projection resulted in an empty tuple thus resulting in the failure of the `tuple.getValues().size()>0` condition inside the filter.

It's worth mentioning also the other variants of each:

```
each(Fields inputFields, Function function, Fields functionFields)
each(Function function, Fields functionFields)
```

These will apply the provided *function* on the projection of the input tuple, appending the resulting tuple to the original input tuple renaming the new fields as *functionFields* (i.e. the projection is only used for applying the *function*).

In particular the second version is equivalent to invoke each with *inputFields* set to null (or `new Fields()`) and will result in an empty tuple getting passed to *function*.